# How to Insert multiple rows into SQLServer2017 with Python

Tags: python, sql-server

Getting this in Python3.7 trying to insert a dictionary to SQL Server
Out of ideas, does this thing actually work with SQL Server/ Is there another method to insert multiple lines using python
The second parameter to executemany must be a sequence, iterator, or generator.

Attempted to change 2nd parameter of excecutemany to iterator, no luck

```
cursor = connStr.cursor()
for key, value in r3.items():
    for idx, x in enumerate(value): 
        x["remotecontrol_id"], idx
        x["device_id"],idx 
        x["alias"], idx
        x["groupid"], idx
        x["online_state"], idx

   sql = ("""INSERT INTO dbo.Tablename[remotecontrol_id], [device_id], [alias],[groupid],
    [online_state])) 
    values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""")
    numRows = cursor.executemany(sq;, x) #pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The second parameter to executemany must be a sequence, iterator, or generator.
```

Comment: it's telling you `x` is not an iterable type, take a look at `x` to see whether it is what you believe it to be, also can you show us what `r3` looks like

Comment: You should read the [pyodbc docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor), the SQL is not formatted as pyodbc expects (though you haven't hit that problem yet).

Comment: Specifically, the param placeholders are qmarks: `?`.

Comment: Thanks all! x is class dict. What should I make it? r3 is JSON it looks like this
'devices': [{'remotecontrol_id': 'rXXXXX', 'device_id': 'd372006383', 'alias': 'WA - WIN10-09

Comment: Ok, I changed some things around, same error though
here it is now 
stmt.executemany("""INSERT INTO dbo.Tablename(remotecontrol_id, device_id, alias,groupid,
    online_state)) 
    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", x)

Comment: Well, tried converting dict to a dataframe, no joy either. I don't think this thing works period, they need to pull it until it gets sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO dbo.Tablename[remotecontrol_id], [device_id], [alias],[groupid], [online_state])) 
        VALUES(%('remotecontrol_id')s, %('device_id')s, %('alias')s, %('groupid')s, %('online_state')s")
```

Comment: Thanks
Now I am getting
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0):

I have tested many methods but this is the **fastest** way to insert bulk of data in MSSQL.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql_database_url = "your_mssql_db_url"

sql_engine = create_engine(sql_database_url)

ab = [tuple((f"Name_{i}",f"Address_{i}",i))
      for i in range(30000)]

tt1 = timer()
with sql_engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as con:
    for i in range(0,30000, 1000):
        chunk = ab[i:i+1000]
        values = ', '.join(map(str, chunk))
    
        con.execute(f"""
        insert into temp(name, location, age)
        values {values}
        """)
print(timer()-tt1)
```

It finished in 1.8s whereas another method finished in 13s and another in 126s.